# HP DL360E error ILO 4: Embedded Flash/SD-CARD: Embedded media manager failed media atta:ch.

Tags: media

When I create Array in this server (ProLiant DL360e Gen8) after in a POST Error

```
iLO 4 has detected a self test error. For details consult the iLO 4 server and iLO 4 diagnostics page
```

Than I see ILO log:

```
Embedded Flash/SD-CARD: Embedded media manager failed media attach.
```

What is mean?
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the internal USB/SDHC card on the motherboard. Please check to see that there's nothing connected internally. If there is something connected, please make sure it is a healthy device.

Answer (score 1):

This is an known bug on ILO4 chips.
HP is providing an firmware update: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ITRC-Remote-Lights-Out-Mgmt-iLO/iLO-4-firmware-version-1-50-released/td-p/6472576#.VAhcMfl_t8E

Comment: ** Updated firmware update link **
Current Version of iLO-4 is v2.4.0 as of Jul 02, 2016: 
http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/servers/ilo/resources.html